# How do we get the response code as the response of an api

Tags: node.js, rest, loopback

For example, I am sending a POST request(http://localhost:5600/api/Abc) using postman, now after completion of this, some response I will get in the body of response, this response mainly contain all the values of the newly added row. So if in the response body, I don't want all the value of this row, instead I want status code like 200 or 500 or 404 or anything. how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: rephrased for better understanding

Comment: Status code is always returned either way.

Comment: can you be more specific where it is returned in response with what name?